# vba Multiply Range with Range

Tags: excel, vba, multiplication

I'd like to multiply the cells of column P with the cells in column M and replace the content of column P with the respective product. Afterwards I want to do the exact same thing with columns Q and N.

I've been trying to look this issue up and the closest solution was: [VBA multiply two named ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790561/vba-multiply-two-named-ranges)

Unfortunately, after running through the first column and calculating it, Excel gives me a runtime error 13 - type mismatch.

My code:

```
Sub rechnen_mod()

Dim aud_y As Range
Dim soc_r As Range
Dim mp_y As Range
Dim mp_r As Range

Set aud_y = Sheets("MRP score template").[P11:P1000]
Set soc_r = Sheets("MRP score template").[Q11:Q1000]
Set mp_y = Sheets("MRP score template").[M11:M1000]
Set mp_r = Sheets("MRP score template").[N11:N1000]

For i = 1 To Range("P").End(xlDown).Row
    aud_y(i, 1) = aud_y(i, 1) * mp_y(i, 1)
Next i

For j = 1 To Range("Q").End(xlDown).Row
    soc_r(j, 1) = soc_r(j, 1) * mp_r(j, 1)
Next j

End Sub
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

EDIT: After reading <stackoverflow.com/a/22056347/11231520> I changed the code to:

```
Public Sub array1()

Dim x As Long
Dim arr
Dim arr_e
Dim arrf
Dim arrf_e
Dim results
Dim r As Range

arr = Sheets("MRP score template").[P11:P473]
arrf = Sheets("MRP score template").[M11:M473]

ReDim results(1 To UBound(arr) * UBound(arrf))

For Each arr_e In arr
    For Each arrf_e In arrf
        x = x + 1
        results(x) = arr_e * arrf_e
    Next arrf_e
Next arr_e

Set r = Sheets("calc").Range("A1:A" & UBound(results))

r = Application.Transpose(results)

End Sub
```

Excel gives me a **runtime error 13 - type mismatch** with the explanation that **arrf_e = error 2402**. After a quick research this should mean that the array contains **#NA** - but it doesn't.

After clicking on debugging, the marked line is

> results(x) = arr_e * arrf_e

Comment: You could pass your ranges in arrays and use the method described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22056347/11231520. The execution will be considerably faster than reading/multiplying/writing for each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below code instead. I also added comments to explain each step :)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub rechnen_mod()
    Dim mp_y() As Variant
    Dim mp_r() As Variant
    Dim aud_y() As Variant
    Dim soc_r() As Variant
    Dim arrResult_P() As Variant
    Dim arrResult_Q() As Variant
    Dim iLastRow As Integer
    Dim iSizeArrays As Integer
    Dim iIndexSearch As Integer
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MRP score template")
        ' Find last row of table, replace it with fixed value if you prefer
        iLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
        
        ' Store data in arrays
        mp_y = .Range("M11", "M" & iLastRow).Value
        mp_r = .Range("N11", "N" & iLastRow).Value
        aud_y = .Range("P11", "P" & iLastRow).Value
        soc_r = .Range("Q11", "Q" & iLastRow).Value
        
        ' Calculate size of arrays
        iSizeArrays = UBound(mp_y) - LBound(mp_y) + 1
        
        ' ReDim result arrays according to iSizeArrays
        ReDim arrResult_P(1 To iSizeArrays)
        ReDim arrResult_Q(1 To iSizeArrays)
        
        ' Calculate result values
        For iIndexSearch = 1 To iSizeArrays
            arrResult_P(iIndexSearch) = mp_y(iIndexSearch, 1) * aud_y(iIndexSearch, 1)
            arrResult_Q(iIndexSearch) = mp_r(iIndexSearch, 1) * soc_r(iIndexSearch, 1)
        Next iIndexSearch
        
        ' Write results in the worksheet
        .Range("P11", "P" & iLastRow) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrResult_P)
        .Range("Q11", "Q" & iLastRow) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrResult_Q)
    End With
End Sub
```

I tested it with random values on 250 rows and it worked fine.

Comment: Hi Vincenct, thank you for your answer and effort! I tried it with 150 rows, and Excel is giving me the runtime error 13 - type mismatch. After debugging it's highlighting following line:
```
 arrResult_P(iIndexSearch) = mp_y(iIndexSearch, 1) * aud_y(iIndexSearch, 1)
```

Comment: To further clarify: "mp_y(iIndexSearch, 1) = error 2042

Comment: @Moritz Please check your data on column P, one of your cells must have ```#N/A```  as value, which is not a valid value. ```error 2042``` is put in an array when the source cell contains ```#N/A``` as a constant or as a result of a formula.

Comment: Hi Vincent, caused by an error there has been an #NA, after eliminating all #NA's it's working perfectly fine. Thanks for your help!